# How to convert version one working url(endpoint) to java query using version one java REST client

Tags: java, rest, versionone

I need to convert below working REST endpoint to java query

> /rest-1.v1/Data/Timebox?Where=Schedule.ScheduledScopes.Name="Sample: Call Center Product"&sel=Workitems:Defect[AssetState='Closed'].Estimate.@Sum,Name,Workitems:Story[AssetState='Closed'].Estimate.@Sum

My Not working Code:

```
IAssetType storyType = services.getMeta().getAssetType("Timebox");
        Query query = new Query(storyType, true);
        IAttributeDefinition name = storyType.getAttributeDefinition("Name");
        IAttributeDefinition defect_estimate = storyType.getAttributeDefinition("Workitems:Defect[AssetState='Closed'].Estimate.@Sum");
        IAttributeDefinition story_estimate = storyType.getAttributeDefinition("Workitems:Story[AssetState='Closed'].Estimate.@Sum");
        query.getSelection().add(name);
        query.getSelection().add(defect_estimate);
        query.getSelection().add(story_estimate);
        //IFilterTerm activeSprint = new TokenTerm("State.Code='ACTV'");
        IFilterTerm activeSprint = new TokenTerm("Schedule.ScheduledScopes.Name='Sample: Call Center Product'");
        query.setFilter(activeSprint);        
        DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset( );
        QueryResult result = services.retrieve(query);
```

Error i am getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.versionone.apiclient.exceptions.MetaException: Unknown AttributeDefinition: Timebox.Workitems:Defect[AssetState='Closed'].Estimate.@Sum
at com.versionone.apiclient.MetaModel.getAttributeDefinition(MetaModel.java:119)
at com.versionone.apiclient.AssetType.getAttributeDefinition(AssetType.java:96)
at v1_rest_intig.Example1.main(Example1.java:230)
```

what am i doing wrong??
any guidance is of great help

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could try with `Workitems:Defect[AssetState='Closed']`, then `Workitems:Defect[AssetState='Closed'].Estimate` ... to find which part of your attribute path is causing the issue.

Comment: I tried replacing as u said but still still the same,I also tried Defect.Estimate.@Sum it gets  closed  and not closed as well and also some repeated assets with NULL value

Comment: I guess its not accepting  this [AssetState='Closed']

Answer (score 2):

You are using the right attribute definition, but apparently, at some version of the API they stop translating symbols, like brakets '[' into the URL encoding ( '%5B'  for open bracket) and therefore the resulting error message.

Please, try this instead:

Workitems:Defect%5BAssetState=%27128%27%5D

for your attributes definition for the Defect/Story AssetType.

Let me know if this works.

TIA,

Comment: I checked the last version to the date , 15.3.+ and this error is still coming up...